# Pushing items to an object key's value array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the array of objects:

```
[
 { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 183 },
 { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 2},
 ...
]
```

I want to rebuild this array as

```
[
 { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: [183, 2] },
 ...
]
```

Here is the code I have written (the code which brings me closest to the desired result anyway):

```
var array = [];

rows.forEach(function(row) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.pair_id = [row.pair_id];
    obj.exchange_pair_id = [row.exchange_pair_id]
    array.push(obj);
});
```

Which results in:

```
[
 { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: [183] },
 { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: [2] },
 ...
]
```

This seems like a very simple problem with a simple solution, but I've been wracking my brains and can't figured it out.

Comment: All you do in `obj.exchange_pair_id = [row.exchange_pair_id]` is wrap the value into an array but not check for similar pair ids. The simplest idea would be using keys in your array.

Comment: A simple if statement of if pair_id: == 1, etc. and then pushing would suffice in my opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution. I iterate over the array by [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and try to find an element in the `groupedArray` by `pair_id` using [**Array#find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function. If the element is found I push the `exchange_pair_id` into the array of that element. If not I create a new item in the array according to the item's values.

```js
const array = [
  { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 183 },
  { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 2},
  { pair_id: 2, exchange_pair_id: 7},
  { pair_id: 3, exchange_pair_id: 988},
  { pair_id: 2, exchange_pair_id: 8},
  { pair_id: 3, exchange_pair_id: 98}
];

const groupedArray = [];

array.forEach(item => {
  
  const found = groupedArray.find(x => x.pair_id === item.pair_id);
  
  if(found) {
     found.exchange_pair_id.push(item.exchange_pair_id);
  } else {
     groupedArray.push({ pair_id: item.pair_id, exchange_pair_id: [item.exchange_pair_id]});
  }
  
});

console.log(groupedArray);
```

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer; will research find() further. I actually feel that I could skip this step by performing a better MySQL query, if you do have a moment of your time to see this it may be a way to skip this step. Really appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365942/mysql-select-all-values-which-share-this-fields-value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var arr1 = [
    { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 183 },
    { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 2},
];

var arr2 = [];
arr1.forEach(el => {
    var obj = arr2.find(it => it.pair_id === el.pair_id);
    if (!obj) {
        el.exchange_pair_id = [el.exchange_pair_id];
        arr2.push(el);
    } else {
        obj.exchange_pair_id.push(el.exchange_pair_id);
    }
});

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: This doesnot produce the desired output!

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just need to check if there's previous results. Using a map is more time efficient than looking through the list with something like `find` every time you see an item.

```
var results = new Map();

rows.forEach(function(row) {
    previous_result = results.get(row.pair_id)
    if (previous_result != null) {
         previous_result.exchange_pair_id.push(row.exchange_pair_id);
    } else {
         var obj = {};
         obj.pair_id = row.pair_id;
         obj.exchange_pair_id = [row.exchange_pair_id]
         results.set(row.pair_id, obj);
    } 
});

Array.from(results.values())
```

Comment: This solution didn't work I'm afraid: Map { 1=> { pair_id: [1], exchange_pair_id: [183] }, ...

Comment: @Nick Happy to help. I tested locally and it seemed to work. What didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is aggregation or reduction, so I'd use `Array.reduce()` here. Take each element in turn and build up a new set of elements, like this:

```js
const rows = [
 { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 183 },
 { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 2},
 { pair_id: 4, exchange_pair_id: 6}
];

const result = rows.reduce( function( aggregate, nextElement ) {
   const pair_id = nextElement.pair_id;        
   
   //create a new row in the aggregate if one doesn't exist
   let aggregatedRow = aggregate.find( r => r.pair_id === pair_id );       
   if ( !aggregatedRow ) {
      aggregatedRow = { pair_id, exchange_pair_id: [] }; 
      aggregate.push( aggregatedRow );
   }
   //add the new exchange pair id to the aggregate row       
   aggregatedRow.exchange_pair_id.push( nextElement.exchange_pair_id );
       
   return aggregate;
       
}, []); //start with an empty array

console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for same `pair_id`.

```js
var array = [{ pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 183 }, { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: 2}],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (!hash[o.pair_id]) {
            hash[o.pair_id] = [];
            r.push({ pair_id: o.pair_id, exchange_pair_id: hash[o.pair_id] });
        }
        hash[o.pair_id].push(o.exchange_pair_id);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```