# MySQL select all values which share this field's value

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am new to MySQL so describing problems in words is difficult and searching for solutions is extremely challenging.

This problem is best explained visually:

I want to select (as an array) exchange_pair_id's that share the same pair_id.

[image: localhost]

So in the above data, my MySQL query would return an object:

```
{ pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: [183, 1] }
```

I am aware this is a butchered question, but I do not know the words to search to solve this problem.

**Updated for clarity/brevity:**

```
+------------------+-------------+---------+
| exchange_pair_id | exchange_id | pair_id |
+------------------+-------------+---------+
| 1                | 3           | 1       |
+------------------+-------------+---------+
| 183              | 1           | 1       |
+------------------+-------------+---------+
| 69               | 2           | 2       |
+------------------+-------------+---------+
| 12               | 4           | 2       |
+------------------+-------------+---------+
| 2                | 3           | 2       |
+------------------+-------------+---------+
| 3                | 3           | 3       |
+------------------+-------------+---------+
```

Desired output from a Javascript MySQL select query:

```
[
 { pair_id: 1, exchange_pair_id: [1, 183] },
 { pair_id: 2, exchange_pair_id: [69, 12, 2] },
 { pair_id: 3, exchange_pair_id: [3] }
]
```

Comment: do you hve just couples or it's possible that you have a third record having pair_id==1?

Comment: I've tried to simplify the question but obviously not the whole picture. I have 300+ "pair_id" values with varying numbers of exchange_pair_id fields. Is this going to require a loop for each pair_id?

Comment: so, can you pls post your desired output if you have say four records with same pair_id (if possibile post desired output as a text table in your question)

Comment: I've just posted some clarity with a larger DB example @etsa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking a query like this , but I'm waiting your answer at comments.
Basically, you use GROUP BY to obtain in two different columns the values for each pair_id:

```
SELECT pair_id, MIN(exhange_pair_id) AS id1, MAX(exchange_pair_id) AS id2
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY pair_id;
```

**Update version:**  Can you try this please on your data?
In this case MYSQL let you concat field using a separator (,)

```
SELECT pair_id, GROUP_CONCAT(exhange_pair_id) AS exhange_pair_id 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY pair_id
```

Comment: Ah, so this would work if there were two values. I have an unknown number of possibly matching values to select.

Comment: @nick as I asked above in question comment, you should post desired output for a variagate sample data input

Comment: @nick: this work for any number of matching values, but gives you only two, using MIN and MAX

Comment: this is working delightfully. I need to read about this GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 0):

try `select exchange_pair_id from yourtable where pair_id=1` then it will return array [1,183]

Comment: you can use group by clause when you need to group data

Comment: Even if I wanted to query by each pair_id it would return individual rows for each where condition

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you are looking for would be:

```
SELECT * WHERE pair_id == 1
```

Without knowing what your specific code looks like, I can only guess as to how you are implementing a call to your database. I would assume you are doing some sort of async call to a PHP controller. So instead of using '1' in the query, you will need to use whatever variable you are pulling from your code to know what you are looking for.